# Async void lambda expressions

Tags: c#, async-await, generic-lambda

A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=avoid%20async%20void&cad=h) will tell you to avoid using `async void myMethod()` methods when possible. And in many cases there are [ways to make it possible](https://johnthiriet.com/removing-async-void/). My question is basically an offshoot of this best practice:

What does the lambda expression below evaluate to?

```
Task.Run( async ()=> await Task.Delay(1000));
```

If it becomes an `async Task` then we are following best practice.

But what if it evaluates to `async void`?

Comment: There seems to be some explanations [here](http://www.thebillwagner.com/blog/Item/2016-05-18-DoasynclambdasreturnTasks). In your specific case, it's gonna resolve to an async function returning a `Task`, so following best practice.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#expression-lambdas) for expression lambdas says,

> An expression lambda returns the result of the expression

So, for example, `() => "hi"` returns a string, even though there is no `return` statement. But if the expression doesn't return anything, like in `() => Console.WriteLine("hi")`, then it's considered `void`.

However there is a bit of trickery with `async` lambdas. The expression `await Task.Delay(1000)` doesn't really return anything in itself. However, the language can figure out that if you have an `async` lambda, you likely want it to return a `Task`. So it will *prefer* that.

So this:

```
Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
```

Is equivalent to this, if you were to express it with a named method:

```
private async Task Wait1000() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
Task.Run(Wait1000);
```

But it is important to note that `async` lambdas *can* be inferred to be `async void`. The only reason it is considered `async Task` here is because `Task.Run` [has an overload for `Func<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__). If the only available overload took an [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action) parameter, then it would be inferred to be `async void`, without any warning to you.

For example, this produces no error and the lambda is treated as `async void`:

```
private void RunThisAction(Action action) {
    action();
}
RunThisAction(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
```

That is different than if you passed it a named `async Task` method, which would cause a compiler error:

```
private void RunThisAction(Action action) {
    action();
}
private async Task Wait1000() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
RunThisAction(Wait1000); // 'Task Wait1000()' has the wrong return type
```

So be careful where you use it. You can always hover over the method name (like the `Run` in `Task.Run`) and Visual Studio will tell you which overload it has inferred:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, it is evaluated to `async Task` because `Task.Delay(n)` has return type of `Task`. So it is good practice.

[In addition, there is msdn example, but it is a little bit more verbose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            await ExampleMethodAsync();
            textBox1.Text += "\r\nControl returned to Click event handler.\n";
        };
    }

    private async Task ExampleMethodAsync()
    {
        // The following line simulates a task-returning asynchronous process.
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

So the above code could be shortened to:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Click += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        textBox1.Text += "\r\nControl returned to Click event handler.\n";
        };
    }
}
```

And now shortened code looks like your code.

Answer (score 0):

As [Documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#explicit-return-type) sayed, beginning with C# 10, you can specify the return type of a lambda expression before the input parameters.

```cs
var fn = async Task (string p1, int p2) =>
{
    // await something
};
```

In case of `Task.Run(..)` refer to Gabriel Luci answer. But I usually specify the Task explicitly to be clear specially in asp.net core Map route methods.