# Adding async value during the interation c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I've a method called by my controller and i'm trying to add new value during the iteration

```
public async Task<MyResult> GetItems(int itemId) {
try
{
    //returns a lists of items
    var resList = await _unit.repository.GetAll(x => x.ItemId.Equals(itemId));

    if(resList.Count() == 0)
        throw new Exception(err.Message);

    //Here i need to list the sub-items, but the method returns async
    resList.ToList().ForEach(async res => {
        switch (res.Type)
        {
            case Itemtype.None :
                res.SubItems = await _unit.repository.GetAll(y => y.ItemId(res.ItemId));
            break;
            case Itemtype.Low :
                //get from another place
            break;
        } 
    });

    return new MyResult { 
        res = resList
    };
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

}

It was shown my Items, but without the sub-items

Comment: As it is, you are iterating over a temporary list (created by `ToList()`) and storing the subitems there, rather than in the original `reslist`. You can fix this if you replace `ToList().ForEach` with a simple `foreach` loop that updates `resList` directly.

Comment: What is `ForEach` method?

Comment: @JohnWu but `ToList` is not creating new `res`'s it is modifying existing ones. I think switching to `foreach` will help but because code will actually `await` for result and will not just create  `resList.Count()` of tasks and return.

Comment: `List.ForEach` + async = [async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). Check out Gabriel Luci's answer in this question: [Async void lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61827597/async-void-lambda-expressions/61828401#61828401)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that using `await` inside a `foreach` loop will pause the iteration until the `Task` completes.

This can lead to pretty poor performance if you have a large number of items.

Allow the tasks to run simultaneously:

```
var tasks = resList.Select(async res =>
{
    switch (res.Type)
    {
        case Itemtype.None :
            res.SubItems = await _unit.repository.GetAll(y => y.ItemId(res.ItemId));
        break;
        case Itemtype.Low :
            //get from another place
        break;
    } 
});
```

Then use `Task.WhenAll` to allow them all to complete:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

`Enumerable.Select` works differently to `List<T>.ForEach` in that it returns from the provided delegate, which in this case is `Task`.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to realize that the `await` keyword will *return* when it acts on an incomplete `Task`. Usually it returns its own incomplete `Task` that the caller can use to wait until it's done, but if the method signature is `void`, it will return nothing.

Whatever that `ForEach()` is, it's likely that it does not accept a delegate that returns a `Task`, which means that your anonymous method (`async res => { ... }`) has a `void` return type.

That means your anonymous method returns as soon as the network request in `GetAll()` is *sent*. Because `ForEach()` isn't waiting for it, it moves on to the next iteration. By the time `ForEach()` is done everything, all it has done is *sent* the requests, but not waited for them. So by the time you get to your `return` statement, you can't be sure anything has been done.

Replace that `.ForEach()` call with just a regular `foreach` so that you aren't doing that work inside a `void` delegate. Then you should see it behave more like you expect. Even better, use [Johnathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62301693/1202807) to start all the tasks inside the loop, then wait for them after.

Microsoft has a very well written series of articles on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) that I think you will benefit from reading. You can find the rest of the series in the table of contents on the left side of that page.

Answer (score 0):

Switch from `resList.ToList().ForEach(...)` to ordinary `foreach`:

```
foreach (var res in resList)
{
    switch (res.Type)
    {
        case Itemtype.None:
            res.SubItems = await _unit.repository.GetAll(y => y.ItemId(res.ItemId));
            break;
        case Itemtype.Low:
            //get from another place
            break;
    }
}
```

It seems that your are using [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netcore-3.1). It accepts `Action<T>` and since the action you pass to it is asynchronous your current code will just create `resList.Count()` of tasks and proceed to return statement without actually awaiting them. Simple reproducer can look like this:

```
class MyClass { public int i; }

var col = new[] { new MyClass { i = 1 }, new MyClass { i = 2 } };
col.ToList().ForEach(async i => { await Task.Delay(1); i.i *= 10; });
//col.ToList().ForEach(i => { i.i *= 10; });

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", col.Select(mc => mc.i))); // will print "1 2"
```

Comment: I'm thinking async should be in front of foreach

Comment: @MikeCheel it seems that OP is using `List<T>.ForEach` which returns `void` .

Comment: i meant in front of your foreach. async in for loops can cause issues (in pre- 7.3(?) I think)  c# and so i typically use Task.WaitAll (or similar). async foreach solves this problem (in c# 8 It hink)? https://medium.com/@t.masonbarneydev/iterating-asynchronously-how-to-use-async-await-with-foreach-in-c-d7e6d21f89fa

Comment: @MikeCheel why do you think that `resList` is `IAsyncEnumerable`? There is no awaiting in `resList.Count()` call, for example.

Comment: @MikeCheel the article you've linked is not about issues it is about possible performance gains, which is up to debate because heavily will be dependent on scenario.

Comment: You're right I don't know why I was thinking that. End of day I guess.